# How to insert a character in a string from a column in SQL

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I had data in a column like:

```
B5AnDiSaAnAnocx1
B5AnDiSaAnAnocx1
B6InInBuNyDachx3
B6InInBuNyElhyx1    
B6InInBuNyElhyx2
B6InInBuNyEuacx1
B6InInBuNyEucox1
B6VeBiCiCiAnosx1
B6VeBiCiCiAnosx7
B6VeBiCiCiAnosx3
```

How can I insert a "00" before the last digit in every data in the column? Suppose the Table name is `sub4` and column name is `id`.

Comment: Can you share your code you wrote that produces the incorrect results?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I am using phpMyadmin, should I remove SQL from the tag?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to reconstruct the field:

```
select concat(left(col, length(col) - 1), '00', right(col, 1))
```

The exact functions differ by database, but the idea should work in any database.

Comment: I got the result by using the code:<br>select concat(left(id, length(id) - 1), '00', right(id, 1)) FROM sub4<br> the result appeared as I expected. Then how to update the database?

Comment: @SagarAdhurya `UPDATE sub4 SET id = CONCAT(LEFT(id, LENGTH(id) - 1), '00', RIGHT(id, 1))`